# "Print" and "ui.Label" return different strings in console and in the UI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working on a variable label in Google Earth Engine and noticed that the label as printed in the console is not the same as the label shown on the map. Why is that? Code below:

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-106.75701284923326, 42.31332966408458],
          [-106.75701284923326, 42.003856624775146],
          [-106.31755972423326, 42.06913460511273]]]);

var chirpsSelect = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
            .filterDate('1985-01-01','2018-01-01')
            .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(3,6))
            .filterBounds(aoi)

var chirpsStartImage = ee.String(chirpsSelect.first().get('system:index'))
var dateStartString = ((((chirpsStartImage.slice(6,8)).cat('/')).cat(chirpsStartImage.slice(4,6))).cat('/')).cat(chirpsStartImage.slice(2,4)) 

var sortChirpsSelect = chirpsSelect.sort('system:index',false)

var chirpsEndImage = ee.String(sortChirpsSelect.first().get('system:index'))
var dateEndString = ((((chirpsEndImage.slice(6,8)).cat('/')).cat(chirpsEndImage.slice(4,6))).cat('/')).cat(chirpsEndImage.slice(2,4))
var dateTitle = ee.String((dateStartString.cat(' to ')).cat(dateEndString))

print(dateTitle)

var dateLabel = ui.Label({
  value: dateTitle
})

var panel = ui.Panel()
panel.add(dateLabel)
Map.add(panel)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the ui.Label needs to print a client side string. You can simply use `.getInfo()` on the dataTitle, but in longer running scripts it's possibly better to asynchronously call `.evaluate()`:

```
var dateLabel = ui.Label({
  value: 'Please wait...'
})
dateStartString.cat(' to ').cat(dateEndString).evaluate(function(val){
                                                 dateLabel.setValue('From: ' + val)});
```

[Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f85792d37c1494a04ff77ac1404bf3ea)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after further research. Is "evaluate" client-side?

Comment: nice use of `evaluate` over `getInfo` @Kuik!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_events

Comment: just a minor detail, you can call `evaluate` in any `ee.ComputedObject` so you could've done: `dateTitle.evaluate(function(val){dateLabel.setValue('From: ' + val)});`.. but the concept of using `evaluate` in ui events for not blocking the app is great =)