# Setting coordinates of map centre from featureCollection geometry?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to set the coordinates of the map centre using the coordinates from a geometry.

```
// randomly select 100 points
points = points.randomColumn('random');
var P = ee.Number(100).divide(points.size());
points = points.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', P));
print (points)

// plot them
Map.addLayer(points);
var centre = points.geometry().centroid().coordinates();
print (ee.Number(centre.get(0)), ee.Number(centre.get(1)));
Map.setCenter(ee.Number(centre.get(0)), ee.Number(centre.get(1)), 9);
// Map.setCenter(-0.06657026751372405, 51.47080255078299, 9);
```

I am getting the error

> Provided center object has invalid values for lat, lon, or zoom.
>   Expected numeric values.

[Link to example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f9358728b33e1308c42b0c35a47c28c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server#client-and-server-functions) any class which does not start with ee.Thing, usually needs client side inputs. Therefore, the Map.setCentre() needs two/three client side numbers. To make your code easily working, use getInfo():

```
Map.setCenter(ee.Number(centre.coordinates().get(0)).getInfo(), 
              ee.Number(centre.coordinates().get(1)).getInfo(), 9);
```

Or use evaluate on longer running results: [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315537/print-and-ui-label-return-different-strings-in-console-and-in-the-ui-in-goog/315539#315539)

Although I would recommend to use another, similar function: centerObject(). That automatically centers the map to the center of a geometry, feature or feature collection and you don't need a getInfo call:

```
Map.centerObject(points, 9);
```